# How to decode facebook links

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, url, character

So whenever I post a link from my website to facebook everything captures correctly and adds images correctly. But when I or any other person clicks on it the link URL get encoded so the address bar has weird characters.
So if the url is example.com/index.php?page=2;article=123
it reads: example.com/index.php%3Fpage%3D2%3Barticle%3D123

Is there any way to add the url a correct way or even have my site check for those characters and redirect it with the correct characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those characters are the html url encoding. The two urls are equivalent and should navigate to the same page. Is your issue with the aesthetics of having those characters show up in the address bar?

Comment: well I do have a javascript code looking for equal signs.
This is the code that does it:
hash = hashes[i].split('=');
Could that be the issue?

Comment: I'm not a javascript developer, but I would imagine that you're not supposed to parse urls manually like that.

Comment: Oh ok, the way I have it set up is to check if it's incoming from Facebook so I have parameters set up for that. Nonetheless thank you, that cleared up alot!